# how to make a function to print a width of an image

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function, that prints a width and height of an image

```js
var a = 3;
var s = 2 * a;
var d = a * s;
print(d);

function cube(y) {
  return y * y * y;
}

var g = cube(3);
print("g: " + g);
print("h: " + cube(99));
var img = new SimpleImage("drewRobert.png");
var imgN = img.setSize(75, 75);
print(img);
var t = new SimpleImage(25, 25);
print(t);
var img9 = new SimpleImage("drewRobert.png");
var img9N = img9.getPixel(77, 90);
print(img9N);
var img8N = img9.getGreen(0, 0);
print(img8N);

function alo(s, f, j) {
  return s + f + j;
}
var sd = alo(9, 3, 1);
print(sd);
img5 = new SimpleImage("palm-and-beach.png");
//that'S one  here 
function printW(w) {
  img5 = new SimpleImage("palm-and-beach.png");
  return w = print(img5.getWidth());
}
print(printW(w));
```

```html
<script src="https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course1/common/js/cs101/SimpleImage.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is `print`and `SimpleImage` and `cube` functions? Can you please update the tags with the libraries you use? - you should use console.log instead of print

Comment: why there's so much code written to just extract the `width` and the `height`? Just create a function and pass the image reference to it, where all you need to use is `.height` and `.width` to it

Comment: I made you a snippet -  I also added js from https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com//course1/

Answer (score 0):

```
function imageInfo(imageName){
    var sampleImage = new SimpleImage(imageName);
    var w = sampleImage.getWidth();
    var h = sampleImage.getHeight();
    return "The height is " + h + " and the width is " + w + ".";

}

result = imageInfo("lion.jpg");
print(result);
```